# Object Size changed after converting an object to ByteArray

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation

I had a method to convert object to byte[] so as to populate PDF in browsers. I can see the inline PDF perfectly, however if I clicked "Save" button and open the downloaded file from my local it will give me the following message:

> "Adobe Reader could not open xx.pdf because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)"

I found out that the data **size difference** during datatype conversion might cause the problem. The size of pdfDataObject pulled out from the database is {byte[1111161]}, which is the same as before it was stored into database; the converted pdfdata is {byte[1111189]}, which increases 28 bytes during the process of conversion.

The datatype of pdf in database is varbinary(max)

```
public byte[] populated_PDF(string args)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    //sqlconnection to get data

    var pdfDataObject = dt.Rows[0]["PDF_DATA"];   
    // get the Varbinary datatype from database
    // The Data Size of pdfDataObject is {byte[1111161]}

    byte[] pdfdata = ObjectToByteArray(pdfDataObject);
    // The Data Size of pdfdata is       {byte[1111189]}

    return pdfdata;
}
```

object to ByteArray method

```
private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The PDF can be displayed in browsers in both size of data. However the one with data size of {byte[1111189]} CANNOT be opened from local if "Save" is applied where the one with data size of {byte[1111161]} can.

Seems like the method ObjectToByteArray added something which causes the failure of opening local downloaded PDF during conversion process.

Don't know how to solve it. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's being changed in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the PDF bytes through a .NET-specific serializer (`BinaryFormatter`)... it's not surprising such a manipulation changes the outcome, as it adds a serialization layer on top of the PDF. Strip it.

This should do the job just fine:

```
return (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["PDF_DATA"];
```